# why I get different output running the same program in two different machine with same specification

Tags: python, centos, biopython, blast

I have a python program which uses bio-python and blast and it accepts the command line. I run this program on Centos 5.3 final. The problem is that I have this on two different machine with exactly as I know same application and same operating system, but in one of them after running a command I get something like "a.data" as output file which is not correct and in the other one i get three files as "a.data.bak", "a.data.dat" and "a.data.dir" which is the correct output.

Do you have any idea what is going on here and why I get different output from the same code on same machine.

Comment: There are an infinite possible answers to your question. What have you investigated so far? Have you read the source code for your program? Have you examined the part of your program that produces output files?

Comment: The codes are the same and also they are using the same version of python. the same version of centos. The same version of biopython and blast.

Comment: That's a good starting place. But I think you need to shift your focus away from "why are the results **different** between A and B" to "why are the results **wrong** on B." Have you tried to debug your program in the failing environment?

Comment: I could do that too but I think this is some type of OS config that it creates .bak(backup file) and .dir and .dat files. don't you think so?